# Gitlab appengine:deploy missing JAR on Gitlab only

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, spring-boot, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have setup a multi module spring boot application including Google appengine integration. Locally everything works fine.

If I do a clean checkout of my GIT repo and after that execute

```
mvn clean install
mvn appengine:deploy
```

The app gets properly deployed to Google appengine

If I try to do the same on gitlab using the following deploy pipeline

```
deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/build
  when: manual
  environment: prod
  script:
  - 'mvn clean install'
  - 'mvn appengine:deploy'
```

I get an error saying:

> Failed to execute goal on project XXX: Could not resolve dependencies
>   for project YYY:XXX:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact
>   YYY:XXX:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Do you have any idea what is wrong/different here? Never had such problems on Gitlab? And I have no idea what is different to the case when I do a clean checkout locally and execute the same commands there?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you are checking it at your local machine. But have you checked it with $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/build manually? I think there is an issue with the docker image itself.